# Executable version isn't fully displayed in Windows 7 shell

Tags: windows, winapi, version

According to the WinAPI executable files may contain resource section. One of the common resource types is the version info (`VERSIONINFO`). It consists of a *fixed* part, plus it may contain arbitrary number of string entries (pairs of name + value).

My build environment is arranged so that whenever I build an executable - its version info is automatically adjusted to reflect the current state of the source control. So that it always contains its build information.

Until last month, when I still worked on the old-good XP machine, I could right-click any such an executable, select properties/version, and - voila! I could see all the build information. But recently I've upgraded my machine to Windows 7. And, as discovered, it doesn't show the rich version info anymore. It shows only the *fixed* version info part.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed? Perhaps there exist an option somewhere to enable the former version info tab?

P.S. The rich version info **is** there, it's not the build problem. I can see this when I open the file with resource editor.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

What I mean by "rich version information".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to this, the version information contains the *mandatory* part (which includes both the product and the file information). Plus it may contain **arbitrary string pairs**. See `StringFileInfo` for more information.

In the version info of my executable I use those custom strings to provide rich source control information (I use SVN).

The revision number goes into the file/product minor version number, there's no problem here. However I also put some custom strings like the following:

- SVN Url = "..."
- Local Modifications = "no"
- Mixed revisions = "Yes, Range=143:177"

and so on.

The Windows XP UI showed all those string in the standard version information tab of the shell. They just disappeared in Windows 7.

The question is how to put them back.

Comment: Does "fixed" refer to `FILEVERSION` or `PRODUCTVERSION`? And I assume "rich" refers to the opposite?

Comment: no. Please see my upcate

Comment: That information is now on the Details tab of the properties dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean that *custom* fields (e.g. non-standard) are no longer displayed.  Sadly this seems to be yet another area where Microsoft dumbed down the interface to the detriment of power users / developers.  The "x minutes ago" in the file times is the bane of my existence.  Anyway, there does not appear to be any built-in way to fix this; looks like someone else already [took care of it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/VersInfoEx2.aspx), though.